# iOS 8 with Xcode 6: PSCollectionView not scrollable and cell not selectable with Tabbed Application

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, pscollectionview

I am using [PSCollectionView](https://github.com/ptshih/PSCollectionView), which is a Pinterest-style waterflow collection view. It is working very well with iOS 7 on Xcode 5&6 and in iOS 8 with Xcode 6, but in **iOS 8** with **Xcode 6** with **TabBarController** as the root controller, the view is not scrollable and cells are not selectable, just like the view is locked, even though it can load the data as normal.

I am wondering what may be the general reason for the collection view that is not scrollable and its cells are not selectable?

This class has already been 2-3 years, there may be some incompatibility within itself. For walking around, do you know there is any other Pinterest-style waterflow collection view that is working well now with iOS 8 with Xcode 6 that I can use instead?

Any ideas are appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout is pretty up to date, so worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

After days trying to figure out this issue, finally got the solution.

It turns out it is nothing to do with the TabBar Controller nor iOS 8, it is the new setting of constraint of Xcode 6. I have to tick the "Installed" even though I already check "xC hR Installed" in the Attribute Inspector of the view used to show PSCollectionView. Now everything is working.

[image]

PS: but still don't know why I have to tick both of them to make it work. Any ideas?